# how to add another reorderable list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I'm learning Flutter and Is it possible to create an reorderable list which has items that are an reorderable List itself (picture below). I'll be really appreciated if someone can suggest me or help me. thanks

This is my code

```
class _ReorderItemsState extends State<ReorderItems> {

  List<String> topTen = [
    "EPL",
    "MLS",
    "LLG",
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: onReorder,
        children: getListItem(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<ExpansionTile> getListItem() => topTen.asMap()
  .map((index, item) => MapEntry(index, buildTenableListTile(item, index)))
  .values.toList();

  ExpansionTile buildTenableListTile(String item, int index) => ExpansionTile(
    key: ValueKey(item),
    title: Text(item),
    leading: Icon(Icons.list),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  );

  void onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex){
    if(newIndex > oldIndex){
      newIndex -=1;
    }
    setState(() {
      String game = topTen[oldIndex];
      topTen.removeAt(oldIndex);
      topTen.insert(newIndex, game);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `children` attribute of `ExpansionTile` widget.

The approach is as follows.

1. You need a common **Data handler** or some sort of state management to keep the state of the parent and children outside the widget to avoid rebuilds when the child list changes. For brevity I am using a singleton to hold the common data. In real case this should be some `ChangeNotifier` or `BLoc` based approach. Not however if you mutate either the parent or child list you need a full rebuild because Flutter, widgets are immutable.

```dart
/// Holding the common data as a singleton to avoid excessive rebuilds.
/// Usually this should be replaced with a manager or bloc or changenotifier class
class DataHolder {
  List<String> parentKeys;

  Map<String, List<String>> childMap;

  DataHolder._privateConstructor();

  static final DataHolder _dataHolder = DataHolder._privateConstructor();

  static DataHolder get instance => _dataHolder;

  factory DataHolder.initialize({@required parentKeys}) {
    _dataHolder.parentKeys = parentKeys;
    _dataHolder.childMap = {};
    for (String key in parentKeys) {
      _dataHolder.childMap.putIfAbsent(
          key, () => ['${key}child_1', '${key}child_2', '${key}child_3']);
    }
    return _dataHolder;
  }
}
```

2. Create a widget which returns a child `ReorderableListView` with unique `ScrollController` for each of these widget. For e.g. a `ReorderList` widget. Its almost identical to what you wrote except I return a `ListTile` instead of `ExpansionTile` and set `scrollController` attribute. Current stable release doesn't have this attribute. So in this solution it is wrapped with a `PrimaryScrollController` widget to avoid duplicate usage of scrollController.

```dart
class ReorderList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String parentMapKey;
  ReorderList({this.parentMapKey});
  @override
  _ReorderListState createState() => _ReorderListState();
}

class _ReorderListState extends State<ReorderList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PrimaryScrollController(
      controller: ScrollController(),
      child: ReorderableListView(
        // scrollController: ScrollController(),
        onReorder: onReorder,
        children: DataHolder.instance.childMap[widget.parentMapKey]
            .map(
              (String child) => ListTile(
                key: ValueKey(child),
                leading: Icon(Icons.done_all),
                title: Text(child),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }
    List<String> children = DataHolder.instance.childMap[widget.parentMapKey];
    String game = children[oldIndex];
    children.removeAt(oldIndex);
    children.insert(newIndex, game);
    DataHolder.instance.childMap[widget.parentMapKey] = children;
    // Need to set state to rebuild the children.
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

3. In the Parent `ExpansionTile` widget set this new widget one of the `children`. This children and the parent are both built from the value of the `DataHolder` singleton class.

   > Note I am setting a constant height to avoid conflicts of layout. You have to play with this for dynamic sizes.

```dart
class ReorderItems extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> topTen;
  ReorderItems({this.topTen});
  @override
  _ReorderItemsState createState() => _ReorderItemsState();
}

class _ReorderItemsState extends State<ReorderItems> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // initialize the children for the Expansion tile
    // This initialization can be replaced with any logic like network fetch or something else.
    DataHolder.initialize(parentKeys: widget.topTen);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PrimaryScrollController(
      key: ValueKey(widget.topTen.toString()),
      controller: ScrollController(),
      child: ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: onReorder,
        children: getListItem(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<ExpansionTile> getListItem() => DataHolder.instance.parentKeys
      .asMap()
      .map((index, item) => MapEntry(index, buildTenableListTile(item, index)))
      .values
      .toList();

  ExpansionTile buildTenableListTile(String mapKey, int index) => ExpansionTile(
        key: ValueKey(mapKey),
        title: Text(mapKey),
        leading: Icon(Icons.list),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        children: [
          Container(
            key: ValueKey('$mapKey$index'),
            height: 400,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: ReorderList(
                parentMapKey: mapKey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

  void onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }
    setState(() {
      String game = DataHolder.instance.parentKeys[oldIndex];
      DataHolder.instance.parentKeys.removeAt(oldIndex);
      DataHolder.instance.parentKeys.insert(newIndex, game);
    });
  }
}
```

A fully working solution is available in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/XWmaGWV).
I changed the code to accept the list of items dynamically from the parent widget. You will have to play with how to maintain the data and reduce rebuilds. But in general a child `ReorderableListView` works as long as the list is maintainted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi..thank you so much for your help but I have an error on key and scrollController. it saying " The named parameter 'scrollController' isn't defined."

Comment: I can see this is not there in the documentation as well. Can you post the output of `flutter doctor`. I am in flutter master channel. Could you try without the scrollController attribute.. It might work. As you can see it works in the codepen, so the issue is with the version we use.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply.. I've attached the screenshot above.

Comment: Looks like there are lot of bugs in `ReorderbleListView` widget in the current stable release. I am not sure when this will be merge and release to a new stable release hopefully nextweek. But until then this code will not work. :( For time being you remove the key and scrollController attributes. I will add an update above. But the Reordering is not maintained in the children widget. :-( You will have to wait for a new release or switch to the master channel.

Comment: oh do you think I can do it using others reorder-able package from pub.dev. My UX team design that so I might need to find alternative route to accomplished that but not sure.. :(

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe they also will suffer from similar bug if they happen to simply wrap this widget.

Comment: Do you know why it's working in Codepen but not in Machine?. pls let me know if you might know alternative solution for this. Thank you

Comment: seems like the reordering is not working in codepen as well. Its not a bug of `ReorderableListView` Widget but the way we build the child itself. The `setState` in the parent is rebuilding the children hence it looses its position. This list has to be maintained in the parent as you did earlier in your code. I will see how to rewrite it and post it. So it should work.. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm not sure reordering for the child is working for in Codepen but I'll wait for you and in the mean time I'll also try to figure out myself. thank you

Comment: Thank you so much and really appreciated for your help. I'm still learning Flutter and  sorry that I keep on bothering you but do you know if I can accomplished like the design above using your code. I want the Parent and Childs to look separated when I added the background color. Right now it look like everything is inside right now (picture above) and it doesn't look like the design I want. thank you

Comment: I want the parents and childs items to have background color and also a gap between them. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212930/discussion-between-abhilash-chandran-and-aasenomad).